# Twitter bootstrap modal fade in and disappears after a half second on manual toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

My modal works fine until i switched the show mode to manual. I call the modal with the following simplified javascript code:

```
var dlg = $('#loginDlg');
dlg.modal({show:false});
if(loggedIn) {
  logout();
} else {
  dlg.modal('show');
}
```

I use bootstrap as a meteor plugin, so only `bootstrap.js` is included.

My markup:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-large span1" id="login" role="button"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginDlg">
  <i class="icon-off pull-right"></i>
</button>
<div class="modal hide fade" id="loginDlg" tabindex="-1"
     role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginDlgLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  ---
</div>
```

Maybe i have to change the markup?

**EDIT:**

The solution: i have to remove the `data-target` attribute in the button markup! With this attribute bootstrap toggles the modal twice.

Comment: Better add the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The solution**: i had to remove the `data-target` attribute in the button markup! With this attribute bootstrap toggles the modal twice.

Comment: How did you target the modal then if you removed the data-target attribute?

Comment: With the javascript code `var dlg = $('#loginDlg');`.